# php checkdnsrr function only works for dotcom domains?

Tags: php

checkdnsrr only works for dot com domains?

If I use live.com (or any existing dotcom), the checkdnsrr returns a value of 1 (TRUE), but it always return a empty string for an existing dot net/org.  It does not matter if the check is for  A or MX or NS... records.  Is the syntax correct or something else?

```
<?php
$dom ="live.net";
$check = checkdnsrr($dom,'NS');
echo "live $check test ";
?>
```

TIA

Comment: The function is not limited to .com domains - no such function is (or should be). Please show examples where it doesn't work so people can try to reproduce.

Comment: if you set $dom = "live.net";  

The echo statement would print "live test", instead of "live 1 test" if $dom = "live.com".

Comment: It works on any domain, but it is recommended to append a period (.) to the end of the domain name. Try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`checkdnsrr()` doesn't return a string at all, it's a BOOL function, so either's true/false. Printing bools out directly is bad practice, because `FALSE` doesn't get turned into a `0` the way `TRUE` becomes `1`. It's cast into an empty string and so is invisible.

At least change your check into something like:

```
echo "$dom test: " . ($check ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE');
```

and get a proper 'true'/'false' text output.

That being said, live.com and live.net both resolve fine here for all sorts of DNS record types. I'd suggest using `'host` or `nslookup` or `dig` on the server you're testing this from to see what they're getting for responses. PHP should be using the same resolver as those tools are.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I know that it is a boolean function, but I think there is something unexplained going on with my network connection.  It is interesting that dotcom is the only tld that works for me.  Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

The code you pasted works for me (TM).

Check your system DNS settings.

Comment: Are you sure it shows "live 1 test" instead of just "live test"?